# Swift Codable: Different coding/encoding strategies

Tags: swift, swift4

I use Perfect framework for server-side development and i want to use same model for database and for JSON response/request (i need to exclude/rename some fields).
Perfect use Codable protocol and own decoder/encoder for DB.
I tried the solution below, but I don't know, maybe there is a better solution?

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var fullName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case username
        case password
        case fullName = "full_name"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let options = encoder.userInfo[CodingOptions.key] as? CodingOptions {
            if options.source == "JSON"
                return try self.decodeFromJson(decoder:decoder)
            }
        } else {
             ...decoder code here..
        }
    }
}               
struct CodingOptions {
    let source: String
    static let key = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "a")!
    init(source: String) {
        self.source = source
    }
}
let options = CodingOptions(source: "JSON")
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
ecoder.userInfo = [CodingOptions.key : options]
let user = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that sort of coupling is a good idea. It now limits the sort of changes you can make to your database (e.g. adding some internal field that you don't want broad cast) and to your JSON api (e.g. adding a computed property whose value is derived from others, and isn't worth storing in the DB)

Comment: In my solution, less RAM is required, i think...

Comment: Why's that? Structs are copied on assignment (and passing as params), so copies are being made left and right any way. Converting from a back end model to a front end model wouldn't be much different.

Comment: @Alexander, if i have an array of structs or classes as result from DB -  i need to create new array for JSON response (additional memory allocation), but if i change encoder method only - i work with existing instances and there is no need to allocate memory for new array.

Comment: Is that memory usage a concern?